# Clarification on the concept of a cumulative distribution function of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

> I was asked to show that $g_f(x)=\mu(f\leq x)$ defines a cumulative
>   distribution function for any measurable function $f$.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ a measurable space. As far as I understand, $\mu(f\leq x)=\mu(\{w\in\Omega:f(w)\leq x\})=\mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, x])$ for $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Given these measurable spaces, $f$ induces the pushforward measure on $\mathcal{B}$ defined by $\mu_f((-\infty, x])=\mu(f^{-1}(-\infty, x])$. But to make $F_{\mu_f}(x)=\mu_f((-\infty, x])$ to be the cumulative distribution function of $\mu_f$, I think it is needed that $\mu$ be finite.

Is my argument going in the right direction?

I'm feeling that something is missing there. Could someone organize the concept of CDF associated to a measure for a better understanding?

Thanks in advance!

---

The definition I hve for a cumulative distribuition function is as follows:

Let $I=[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{B}(I)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(I,\mathcal{B}(I))$. A **cumulative distribution function** of $\mu$ is a function $g_{\mu}:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g_{\mu}(x)=\mu[a,x],\forall x \in I$.

The definition above seems to require that the original statement be restricted to

> Show that $g_f(x)=\mu(f\leq x)$ defines a cumulative
>   distribution function for any measurable function $f:(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow (I,\mathcal{B}(I)) $ and any $\mu$ finite on $\mathcal{F}$.

So if I assume $f:\Omega\rightarrow I, (\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(I))$-measurable and assume $\mu$ finite on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, then $\mu_f=\mu\circ f^{-1}$ will be finite on $(I,\mathcal{B}(I))$ and I might finish the proof, on the lines of my argument above.

Comment: Your definition of cumulative distribution function is too restrictive. Find the general definition from your source. The definition should not invole any finite interval $I$ and the result you are trying to prove would not require any proof if you have the right definition.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I agree with you that this definition is strange, but this is what I have to use. Please, check the last paragraph above . Does that make sense?